# Regex pattern for ex "w l" should match sentences starting with 2 words one with "w" and another with "l"

Tags: regex

For ex :
Lets say "Welcome Lion" is the string then if the user types "W L" then that string should match.
Please give regex pattern for this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Why should "W L" match, how should the code function in general, and what exactly does this have to do with "using \b twice in regex to find a matching string"?

Comment: sorry not necessarily \b.......it could be anything. for ex new RegExp("\\bw" + , "gi"); matches first word Welcome but i want to match Lion as well hence i tried new RegExp("\\bw\bl" + , "gi"); bu does not match this string

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this :

```
entered_string = "W L";
matching_string = "Welcome Lion";
if matching_string.replace(/[^[:upper:]]/g, "").equals(entered_string) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Note that this is pseudo code and won't probably compile in any language.

```
matching_string.replace(/[^[:upper:]]/g, "")
```

This part removes each non uppercase letter.

But then as jwodder said I don't get what you were wondering about 2 \b.

Comment: sorry not necessarily \b.......it could be anything.
for ex  
     new RegExp("\\bw" + , "gi");  matches first word Welcome but i want to match Lion as well hence i tried 
     new RegExp("\\bw\bl" + , "gi"); bu does not match this string

Comment: `(\w).*?\b` : This does match both words and returns the first letter.

Comment: but where is w and l in your pattern?
your pattern will match any 2 words but i want to match only if first letter of first word is W and first letter of second word is L.

another ex:
if the user types "u s" in search box then united states should match and not any 2 word sentence

Answer (score -1):

Finally the following pattern works

```
var char1 = "w";
var char2 = "l";
var regex_str = "\\b" + char1 + "(\\w).*?" + "\\b" + char2;
new RegExp(regex_str, "gim");
```

now change char1 and char2 as per user input and this code should work for any case

@yami please update if you find this answer helpful